# Progressive Web App wrong path

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, progressive-web-apps

I'm working into progressive Web App using C# MVC Template, my appy works online but when I try to use it on 
Android as desktop application using "Add to Home Screen". Problem is when I try to run appi in home, it load 
unknow source "/index", I try using "/Home/Index" but it doesnt work too

This path is changed into manifest.JSON

```
 "start_url": "/index",


 "display": "standalone",

 "background_color": "#3E4EB8",

 "theme_color": "#2F3BA2"
```

Can anyone explian me what path I need to use here to my api works as progressive webApp on android? Regards

Note: Here is my application URL [MyAPI](http://gera123-001-site1.ctempurl.com/)

Answer (score 0):

It's because your app is not available in `http://gera123-001-site1.ctempurl.com/index` path.

You just need to change your `start_url` to `"/"`.